# In which mathematical space do magnetic fields live in?

Tags: electromagnetism

A magnetic field may be described as a mapping $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore, it is a function, and apparently can be described as an element in a function space. Is there some particular (perhaps Hilbert) space that magnetic fields belong to?

Comment: For Maxwell's equations in vacuum ∫dx^3(E^2+B^2) is a conserved quantity so B is square integrable.

Comment: Search in http://www.geuz.org/publications/01.ulg.geuzaine.PhD.pdf for "house". This gets you to Maxwell's house. More precisely: Section "1.3.2 Maxwell’s house".

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link to the PhD thesis. So the short answer is: Hilbert space $\boldsymbol{L}^2(\Omega)$ of square integrable vector fields.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\vA{{\vec A}}\def\vB{\vec{B}}\def\vH{{\vec H}}\def\vS{{\vec S}}\def\vpsi{{\vec\psi}}\def\div{{\rm div}}\def\grad{{\rm grad}}\def\rot{{\rm rot}}\def\rmr{{\rm r}}\def\pd{\partial}\def\nR{{\mathbb{R}}}\def\ltag#1{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
It strongly depends on what you want to model. If you want to include dipoles in your model you must switch to distribution spaces. But, let us keep in a subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$.

The space $L^2(\Omega)$ is too big to give equations like
\begin{align}
\div\vB &= 0.
\end{align}
sense. On the other hand one often has discontinuities of $\mu_\rmr$ at some boundary layers. There the tangent component of $\vB$ can be discontinuous and $\div$ in the classical context does not make sense.

Therefore one must switch to generalized derivatives. The integration by parts rule
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \psi\cdot \div(\vB) d V &= \int_{\pd\Omega} \psi\; \vB\cdot d\vA
- \int_{\Omega} \grad(\psi) \cdot \vB dV\ltag{weakDiff}
\end{align}
is used to transfer the differentation from $\vB$ to test functions $\psi$ and one uses the right hand side to define the generalized $\div$ operator.

If there is a $L^2$ function "$b$" such that
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \psi b\; d V &= \int_{\pd\Omega} \psi\; \vB\cdot d\vA
- \int_{\Omega} \grad(\psi) \cdot \vB dV
\end{align}
for all smooth $\psi$ with bounded support in $\bar\Omega$ then we define the generalized divergence operator for $\vB$ as $\div\vB:=b$ and we say that for $\vB$ there exists the weak divergence on $\Omega$. The space $H(\div,\Omega)$ is the set of all $L^2$-functions on $\Omega$ for which there exists the weak divergence.

Note, that the surface integral in \ref{weakDiff} must be treated in special manner, since the surface is actually a set of zero measure in $\nR^3$. If we would only use $L^2(\bar \Omega)$ then we could modify $\vB$ on $\partial\Omega$ arbitrarily. Therefore, the $\vB$-field on the boundary is actually to be understood as the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator) of the field on the boundary. For the trace to exist there are additional restrictions on the boundary of $\Omega$ (piecewise $C^1$, edges not too "sharp"). Thus, not all domains $\Omega$ are really appropriate for modeling of magnetic fields.

---

Note, that the situation is similar for Ampere's law
\begin{align}
\rot\vH = \vS
\end{align}
where we need $\rot\vH$. The normal component of the field strength can be discontinuous at boundary layers. In this case one uses the equation
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\vpsi\cdot \rot(\vH)dV = \int_{\pd\Omega}\vpsi\cdot(d\vA\times\vH) + \int_{\Omega} \vH\cdot \rot(\vpsi) dV
\end{align}
to define a generalized curl operator $\rot\vH$. The set of fields for which $\rot\vH\in L^2(\Omega)$ is named $H(\rot,\Omega)$.

Interestingly, $\vB$ and $\vH$ live in different spaces and $\mu$ must mediate between these spaces $\mu:\vH\in H(\rot,\Omega)\mapsto \vB=(\mu\vH)\in H(\div,\Omega)$.